# How to disable smtp via web.config

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp, web-config

I'm looking through [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/smtp-element-network-settings), but I'm just not seeing how I can just disable emails. I'm afraid that if I just remove the SMTP element from the web.config, that the code that attempts to send the emails will start throwing errors. I could specify a `pickupDirectoryLocation`, but I worry the directory will max out the hard drive space after a while.

Comment: Why don't you just create a flag to disable the email feature?  The only way to disable the smtp server is to stop the service, but then you would still get errors when someone tried to use it, just as if you had just removed the SMTP element from the web config.

Comment: @BobGeiger, I need a way to do this without doing a code deploy. Our next code deploy is too far away and our users are getting too many emails currently.

Comment: I think you're out of luck then.  You can remove the element, but you're going to get errors.  That's really all you can do since there is no way to disable it that isn't going to generate errors, since your code expects it to function, and it won't.

Comment: Dear anonymous downvoter, why? Please let me know how I can improve the question.